# Replacing Null Values in a Table with Values from other Table

Tags: db2

Here are two tables:

**table_a**:

```
name year  var
---------------
john 2010    a
john 2011    a
john 2012    c
alex 2020    b
alex 2021    c
tim  2015 NULL
tim  2016 NULL
joe  2010 NULL
joe  2011 NULL
jessica 2000 NULL
jessica 2001 NULL
```

**table_b**

```
    name year var
    --------------
    sara 2001   a
    sara 2002   b
     tim 2005   c
     tim 2006   d
     tim 2021   f
 jessica 2020   z
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- Take names that have NULL values in `table_a`
- See if these names appear in `table_b`
- If yes, then see if the name (`table_a`) has a row in `table_b` with a year (`table_b`) that occurs BEFORE the year in `table_a`
- If yes, replace the NULL in `table_a` with the value of var (`table_b`) that is closest to the earliest year (`table_a`)
- Otherwise, keep as is

I tried this:

```
 WITH min_year AS (
    SELECT name, MIN(year) as min_year
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY name
  ),
  b_filtered AS (
    SELECT b.name, MAX(b.year) as year, b.var
    FROM table_b b
    INNER JOIN min_year m ON b.name = m.name AND b.year < m.min_year
    GROUP BY b.name
  )
  SELECT a.name, a.year, 
    CASE 
      WHEN a.var IS NULL AND b.name IS NOT NULL THEN b.var
      ELSE a.var
    END as var_mod
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN b_filtered b
  ON a.name = b.name;
```

But I got the wrong output:

```
 name year var_mod
    john 2010       a
    john 2011       a
    john 2012       c
    alex 2020       b
    alex 2021       c
     tim 2015    NULL
     tim 2016    NULL
     joe 2010    NULL
     joe 2011    NULL
 jessica 2000    NULL
 jessica 2001    NULL
```

Correct output should be:

```
name year var_mod
    john 2010       a
    john 2011       a
    john 2012       c
    alex 2020       b
    alex 2021       c
     tim 2015       d
     tim 2016       d
     joe 2010    NULL
     joe 2011    NULL
 jessica 2000    NULL
 jessica 2001    NULL
```

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the handy `TABLE` clause, which allows you to use a "parameterized" sub-select as below.

```
WITH 
  table_a (name, year, var) AS 
  (
    VALUES
      ('john',    2010, 'a' )
    , ('john',    2011, 'a' )
    , ('john',    2012, 'c' )
    , ('alex',    2020, 'b' )
    , ('alex',    2021, 'c' )
    , ('tim',     2015, NULL)
    , ('tim',     2016, NULL)
    , ('joe',     2010, NULL)
    , ('joe',     2011, NULL)
    , ('jessica', 2000, NULL)
    , ('jessica', 2001, NULL)
  )
, table_b (name, year, var) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('sara',    2001, 'a')
    , ('sara',    2002, 'b')
    , ('tim',     2005, 'c')
    , ('tim',     2006, 'd')
    , ('tim',     2021, 'f')
    , ('jessica', 2020, 'z')
  )
SELECT a.NAME, a.YEAR, COALESCE (a.var, b.var) AS VAR_MOD
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN TABLE 
(
  SELECT b.var
  FROM table_b b
  WHERE b.name = a.name and b.year < a.year
  ORDER BY b.year DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) b ON 1=1
```

The result is:

| NAME | YEAR | VAR_MOD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 2010 | a |
| john | 2011 | a |
| john | 2012 | c |
| alex | 2020 | b |
| alex | 2021 | c |
| tim | 2015 | d |
| tim | 2016 | d |
| joe | 2010 |  |
| joe | 2011 |  |
| jessica | 2000 |  |
| jessica | 2001 |  |

**Update:**

Another much less efficient way with a number of additional the same table references:

```
WITH b_filtered AS 
 (
   SELECT a.NAME, MAX (b.YEAR) AS YEAR
   FROM table_a a
   JOIN table_b b ON b.NAME = a.NAME AND b.YEAR < a.YEAR
   GROUP BY a.NAME
 )  
SELECT a.NAME, a.YEAR, COALESCE (a.var, b.var) AS VAR_MOD
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN 
(
  b_filtered f 
  JOIN table_b b ON b.NAME = f.NAME AND b.YEAR = f.YEAR
) ON f.NAME = a.NAME
```

Comment: thanks so much Mark! do you think you can help me change my original query to achieve this result? Ideally I would like to keep as much of my original query as possible ...

Comment: @user123945 Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used the `LEFT JOIN TABLE` clause. How does it differ from `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`?

Comment: Ah, they are synonyms.

Comment: thanks so much mark ... unfortunately I am still not getting the same result as you are: https://imgur.com/a/9TlhPUd

Comment: (btw I am running the SQL in sqldf package via R Studio/R programming language)

Comment: Please, provide some fully reproducible example with the corresponding CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements.

Comment: my apologies - I did as you suggested and now everything works well!

Comment: I tired to adapt your code for a similar problem  - did I do it correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901470/combining-inner-joins-and-between-statements-in-the-same-query

Answer (score 1):

The statement you showed cannot produce the output shown.
You have to change "GROUP BY b.name" in the b_filtered CTE
to

```
 GROUP BY b.name, b.var
```

and it will produce the desired output.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (name varchar(10), year int , var varchar(10));

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES 
('john', 2010 ,   'a'),
('john', 2011 ,   'a'),
('john', 2012 ,   'c'),
('alex', 2020 ,   'b'),
('alex', 2021 ,   'c'),
('tim',  2015 ,NULL),
('tim',  2016 ,NULL),
('joe',  2010 ,NULL),
('joe',  2011 ,NULL),
('jessica', 2000, NULL),
('jessica', 2001 ,NULL)




CREATE TABLE table_b (name varchar(10), year int , var varchar(10));
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES 
  ('sara', 2001,   'a'),
    ('sara', 2002,   'b'),
     ('tim', 2005 ,  'c'),
     ('tim', 2006 ,  'd'),
     ('tim', 2021  , 'f'),
 ('jessica', 2020  , 'z')
 
 
  WITH min_year AS (
    SELECT name, MIN(year) as min_year
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY name
  ),
  b_filtered AS (
    SELECT b.name, MAX(b.year) as year, b.var
    FROM table_b b
    INNER JOIN min_year m ON b.name = m.name AND b.year < m.min_year
    GROUP BY b.name, b.var
  )
  SELECT a.name, a.year, 
    CASE 
      WHEN a.var IS NULL AND b.name IS NOT NULL THEN b.var
      ELSE a.var
    END as var_mod
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN b_filtered b
  ON a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: thanks Michael! I tried your code and it did not work ... maybe I am misunderstanding something ... could you please write the full query? thank you!

Comment: @user123945 I have added the full SQL

Comment: thanks Michael ... unfortunately I am still not getting the desired result: https://imgur.com/a/4jkgLjD

Comment: (btw I am running the SQL in sqldf package via R Studio/R programming language)