# Combining Inner Joins and Between Statements in the Same Query

Tags: db2

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  name VARCHAR(255),
  date_1 DATE
);


INSERT INTO table_a (name, date_1) VALUES
('john', '2010-01-01'),
('john', '2012-02-01'),
('john', '2017-08-01'),
('sara', '2008-04-01'),
('sara', '2011-04-01'),
('tim', '2000-01-01'),
('tim', '2001-01-01'),
('alex', '2013-01-01');


CREATE TABLE table_b (
  name VARCHAR(255),
  date_2 DATE,
  date_3 DATE,
  var CHAR(1)
);


INSERT INTO table_b (name, date_2, date_3, var) VALUES
('john', '2001-01-01', '2015-01-01', 'b'),
('sara', '2000-01-01', '2015-01-01', 'c'),
('sara', '2015-01-02', '2022-01-01', 'a'),
('tim', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', 'a'),
('john', '1998-01-01', '1999-01-01', 'd');
```

They look like this:

```
#table_a
      name     date_1
 john 2010-01-01
 john 2012-02-01
 john 2017-08-01
 sara 2008-04-01
 sara 2011-04-01
  tim 2000-01-01
  tim 2001-01-01
 alex 2013-01-01

 #table_b
  name     date_2     date_3 var
 john 2001-01-01 2015-01-01   b
 sara 2000-01-01 2015-01-01   c
 sara 2015-01-02 2022-01-01   a
  tim 2020-01-01 2021-01-01   a
 john 1998-01-01 1999-01-01   d
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Part 1: Exact Join

- For rows in table_a and table_b (based on name) -  see if date_1 falls between a pair of (date_2, date_3) within table_b. If yes,then join

Part 2: Window Join

- For rows that were not joined in Part 1 (i.e. could include names that were analyzed in part 1), see if these names appear in table_b
- If yes, then see if the name (table_a) has a row in table_b with a date_2 that occurs BEFORE the date_1
- If yes, then join on row closest to the earliest date_1
- Otherwise, no join

Here is the code I am using:

```
# random ID approach : faster

WITH exact_join AS (
  SELECT a.*, b.var, random() as random_id
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name AND a.date_1 BETWEEN b.date_2 AND b.date_3
),
window_join AS (
  SELECT a.*, b.var
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, var, date_2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_2 DESC) as rn
    FROM table_b
  ) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.date_1 > b.date_2
  WHERE b.rn = 1 AND a.random_id NOT IN (SELECT random_id FROM exact_join)
)
SELECT * FROM exact_join
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM window_join;

# non-random id approach (slower)

WITH exact_join AS (
  SELECT a.*, b.var, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as id
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name AND a.date_1 BETWEEN b.date_2 AND b.date_3
),
window_join AS (
  SELECT a.*, b.var
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as id
    FROM table_a
  ) a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, var, date_2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_2 DESC) as rn
    FROM table_b
  ) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.date_1 > b.date_2
  WHERE b.rn = 1 AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM exact_join)
)
SELECT * FROM exact_join
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM window_join;
```

I think the code is giving the correct output:

```
  name     date_1  var id
 john 2010-01-01    b  1
 john 2012-02-01    b  2
 john 2017-08-01 <NA>  3
 sara 2008-04-01    c  4
 sara 2011-04-01    c  5
  tim 2000-01-01 <NA>  6
  tim 2001-01-01 <NA>  7
 alex 2013-01-01 <NA>  8
```

Is this the correct use of the `random()` function to prevent rows from analyzed twice or skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the result you are showing is incorrect according to the rule:

> If yes, then see if the name (table_a) has a row in table_b with a date_2 that occurs BEFORE the date_1

In that case the third occurrence of John should have matching values instead of empty values. But which one: `b` or `d`? I chose the latest one according to dates (`b`).

You can do:

```sql
select a.name, a.date_1, b.var
from table_a a
left join lateral (
  select * from table_b b where b.name = a.name and b.date_2 < a.date_1
  order by b.date_2 desc fetch next 1 rows only
) b on 1 = 1
```

Result:

```
 NAME  DATE_1      VAR  
 ----- ----------- ---- 
 john  2010-01-01  b    
 john  2012-02-01  b    
 john  2017-08-01  b    
 sara  2008-04-01  c    
 sara  2011-04-01  c    
 tim   2000-01-01  null 
 tim   2001-01-01  null 
 alex  2013-01-01  null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ixa1qo4o).

Now, if you are interested on improving the join performance you can create the index:

```sql
create index ix1 on table_b (name, date_2);
```

**Extra solution without lateral joins (for the same price)**

Without the lateral join the query won't be as performant since you'll need that *nasty* double join. You can do:

```sql
select a.name, a.date_1, b.var
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.name = a.name and b.date_2 = (
  select max(date_2) from table_b c where c.name = a.name and c.date_2 < a.date_1
)
```

The fiddle is updated.

Comment: thank you! is it possible to do this without the "lateral" statement? I am planning on using this SQL on different platforms and ideally would like to have the code that uses as many common statements as possible

Comment: "is it possible to do this without the "lateral" statement?" -- It can be done, but not in a performant way (it's going to be slow). Now, lateral joins are available at least in Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and MySQL. Which other database are you considering?

Comment: ex: netezza ...